# MySQL - Records that don't exist in another table - showing incorrect results

Tags: mysql, join, insert, records

This is my first post here.

I'm trying to display records from one table into another where they do not already exist using an outer join.

```
SELECT a.fname,a.lname,a.dob_month,a.dob_year
FROM new_person a LEFT JOIN person b
USING (fname,enter code herelname,dob_month,dob_day,dob_year,gender,zipcode)
WHERE (b.fname is null and b.lname is null and b.dob_year is null and b.dob_month is null)
```

---

The issue is, when I tested this query it it still shows me records that DO exist.  I believe it has to do with the zipcode being null though i don't know why..

The "new_person" table only has 2 records that don't exist in the "person" table, but when i run this query it gives me 111 records.

However, if i remove the zipcode from the join clause it shows me the correct result of 2 records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `EXISTS` like

```
SELECT a.fname,
a.lname,
a.dob_month,
a.dob_year
FROM new_person a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM person WHERE fname <> a.fname);
```

(OR) even using `LEFT JOIN` what you have already tried

```
SELECT a.fname,
a.lname,
a.dob_month,
a.dob_year
FROM new_person a 
LEFT JOIN person b ON a.fname = b.fname
WHERE b.fname is null;
```

Again, I see that you are joining on all the columns. Not sure why? Is there any relationship exists between the tables? If so, then try joining on that related column rather.